# The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. (is not marked as serializable)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, mstest

I'm using VS 2015 Enterprise and trying to get my unit tests to read data directly from the test case, which is in TFS 2013. Currently I´m getting the following error when trying to connect through the datasource.

> Result Message:    The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data
>   source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting
>   this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests"
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library.
>   Error details: Type
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestObjectNotFoundException'
>   in Assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is
>   not marked as serializable.

My test method looks like this.

```
[TestMethod]
[DataSource("TfsDataSource")]
public void Test1()
{
     string expected = "t1";
     string actual = TestContext.DataRow["actual"].ToString();
     Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

And my config sections like this:

```
   <section name="microsoft.visualstudio.testtools" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestConfigurationSection, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestCaseConnection" connectionString="http://tfsurl/DefaultCollection;projectname" providerName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
    <dataSources>
      <add name="TfsDataSource" connectionString="TestCaseConnection" dataTableName="103217" dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>
    </dataSources>
  </microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
```

Have searched for a solution for some time now but haven´t found anything that matches this issue, so all help or input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your test method on my side, which can work. You can follow my steps below to have another try:

First, insert parameter `actual` in a test case in TFS. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

Then, create an Unit Test Project. Check the code below:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;


namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase", "http://tfsurl:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection;teamprojectname", "TestCaseID", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
        public void Test1()
{
    string expected = "t1";
    string actual = TestContext.DataRow["actual"].ToString();
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get { return testContextInstance; }
            set { testContextInstance = value; }
        }
        private TestContext testContextInstance;
    }
}
```

Last, add a .testsettings file, and select this testsettings file. Now run test, you should get a successful test.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion. I´ve tried that and it returns the same error. Do you have any other suggestions that I can try? Really trying to find a solution for this. Is it possible that I need to change something in TFS do make this work.

Comment: I´ve tried what you are suggesting without success. The test works fine through TFS when using other datasources such as excel or csv.In your testsettings file, are you specifying anything particular? Have tried with both testsettings and runsettings.

Comment: I have just added a default .testsettings file, without any modification. Did you specify port number for your TFS url: http://tfsurl:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection ?

Comment: Ok, I´m still getting the same error, using a default .testsettings file. Is it possible it has to do anything with TFS permissions? Are there any setttings in the TFS that needs to be added/changed? This is our Corporate TFS I´m trying to read from, can it be done using Visual Studio online as well, just trying to exclude the possibilities of it being our TFS...

Comment: Glad to say that I have sorted this out now. It failed because of a bad url. The default url for our server contains spaces which I replaced with %20 which then caused the error. When using traditional spaces it started working. Thanks for all your help and suggestions. :)

Comment: I was getting the same error message and found that the problem was occurring because I changed Default Processor Architecture from x86 to x64, trying to fix another issue. Changing it back to x86 fixed my problem. (Test - Test Settings - Default Processor Architecture)